# how to enable logcat in eclipse when the project running in external device in android?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Im using an application in android. I want to enable logcat in eclipse when the project running in external device. Im trying to load the application when USB Cable is mounted to system. But Im not able to saw anything in logcat and cant acess the device view also. If anyone know about this please help me..

Answer (score 3):

Add the devices view and then select the device there and you should be able to see the log.

Comment: Hi Maria, I cant access the device view. can you help me to acess the device view.

Comment: Window - Show View - Devices (it might be hidden in other...)

Comment: when im running the project, it displays only system emulator view in that Devices. It cant acess the device address.. could u help me to solve it..

Comment: did you activate usb debugging on your device? if you're using windows: check in the windows device manager if your device is recognized correctly, otherwise install the drivers. You might also have to install the Google USB Driver package in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure more than 1 devices are attached to your PC, among that 1 may be an emulator and other may be real devices(i.e. either mobile or tablet).

So whenever you are having multiple devices, at that time first check the devices attached to your system by using `adb devices` command at command prompt.

Once you are having `serialnumber`, you need to run the below command:

**Solution**: `$ adb -s <serialnumber> logcat`

**PS:**
If you just use adb logcat while having multiple devices attached your PC, then below message are being continuously raised:

```
error: more than one device and emulator
- waiting for device -
```

Comment: Hi Paresh, when im running the app when connected to device, it doesnt loads device emulator. it directly loads the system emulator. i want to load the device. could u help me?

Comment: make sure you are developing application with the same SDK version as phone have. If you are having phone with 2.2 version then you should developed with 2.2 version or lower.

Comment: I developed 2.3.3 version project and using 2.3.3 version tab. Is it works in that version?

Comment: @Binu now are you able to run the application on tablet perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

It should work with no problem (I did nothing and works)

Maybe you're using a filter of another application.

On the left column (in LogCat view), choose to see "All messages" or create a filter of your own for that application.